# Good place to identify white bugs in soil

Tags: identification, bugs

I've searched for "white bugs in soil" but that turns up a lot of results.  Is there a website which asks you a set of questions and helps you narrow down what the bugs could be and if they're harmful / helpful?  I have included the image below incase anyone knows what it is but I don't want to add another "White bugs in soil!" question to Gardening stackexchange if I can help it!  ;-D

It's about 8 mm long:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks  like an insect grub / larva. So search "insect larva, soil ".